# Redundant Database

Tags: database

This has been killing me for weeks - I'm finally breaking down and asking for advice.

I'm currently in the process of setting up database servers for a startup web application. The application manages real-time payments at retailers, **so downtime and redundancy are huge factors.** I would like to keep an offsite hot backup as well in case we have a region failure.

**PCI is also something we are bound to.**

Initially, I investigated some MySql solutions such as NDB, Percona Cluster, MMM, and master/slave setups. After a ton of research, I don't think any of these systems could work - simply because of either downtime with failure or the high probability of data corruption.

I've since started looking at databases like mongodb and crunchbase, I feel like I'm just wondering aimlessly looking for a perfect solution, but I doubt I will find one.

I would really appreciate any guidance!

Comment: How many millions of dollars do you have to spend?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Heh, I wish! Bootstrapping it with some ec2 nodes to start off with. That's the main reason redundancy matters. Those nodes can drop in a heartbeat.

Comment: You're trying to build a commercial business, which other companies will depend on, around a technological capability that you don't have and are trying to get from a free Q&A website instead of hiring an expert. Enjoy the flames, chief.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't do that - find someone who will do it for you with some simple drop in code and let them worry about it. Sure it'll cost you a bit but look at what it's cost you already - *weeks* and you don't yet know where to start.

Do everyone a favour and **don't roll your own**.

Comment: Mind you, if it's a startup, this might the service that they're selling. In which case, it's not one of their core competencies, so this will be an entertaining diversion for observers. And, also too, PCI.

Comment: @mfinni: If they're doing that I want to know who their customers are so I can avoid them.

Comment: I absolutely would - given the chance, but as @mfinni stated, we are tied to PCI unfortunately. I apologize for not stating that beforehand.

Comment: Please clarify...what does "this might the service" mean? ALso there are *LOTS* of *DUE DILIGANCE* things in this space....Find something like salesforce.com or go for oracle....or an existing package..

Comment: I did find http://www.pablowe.net/2010/04/pci-dss-mysql-requirement-3. Oracle has all sorts of Point-in-time and recover-in-x-blocks. Multiple destinations are also easy under oracle. I know. I have/had an Oracle certification but they are under serious fire.

Comment: Jonathon - your understanding of PCI is flawed if you think that you can't use vendors for parts of your payment processing.

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly couldn't simple MySQL / Percona replication work for offsite mirroring of data?

If the master goes down, just point the clients to the slave. In the meanwhile, build a new slave. If the new master goes down, repeat the process.

Comment: There would be a minute of downtime when switching master/slave. Downtime means our end customer cannot run transactions which is a HUGE issue.

Comment: the promotion of the master can be triggered when the first transaction fails if you wanted to code it that way. have the "clients" point to a load balancer and have the load balancer point to the current master. or if there really is only one client (the web application code), then pointing would be even easier.